# How to solve a Custom Optimisation problem which uses Matrix Factorisation and custom loss in Pytorch?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch, torch

I am trying to replicate the paper [Recommendation for Effective Standardized Exam Preparation](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3448139.3448177) where they have used a special term called **correctness probability function** and is described as:

> correctness probability function `p`, we use the Matrix
> Factorization model introduced in [this paper](http://ml4ed.cc/attachments/LeeLCCS.pdf). With the question-
> response sequences of the users, we find the decomposition `X = L*R_Transpose` that minimizes the Binary Cross Entropy (BCE) loss with a
> Frobenius norm regularization, where `L = (L_uj )` represents the
> understanding of a student `u` on a hidden concept `j` and `R = (R_qj )`
> represents the contribution of a hidden concept `j` to the question `q`.
> The entry `X = (X_uq)` represents the understanding of a student `u` on
> a question `q`, and the response correctness probability `p(q|I_u ) = P_uq`
> is computed using `X_uq` based on the variation of the M2PR latent
> trait model in IRT give nin [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BF03203665.pdf).

Then they go on to define the exact process like the below image:
[image]

Now they have a modified version of Sigmoid called `phi` which uses 3 additional parameters as `phi_a = 0.25, phi_b = 0.5, phi_c = 10`. My implementation for `phi` is as follows:

```
# Modified sigmoid function
def phi(x, phi_a = phi_a, phi_b = phi_b, phi_c = phi_c):
    '''
    Putting value of X in phi will give the probability score of that question
    According to the paper it is given that Custom sigmoid = phi:
    φ(x) = φ_a + ((1 - φ_a) / (1 + e^ -φ_c(x - φ_b ))) and values of (φ_a , φ_b , φ_c ) are (0.25, 0.5, 10) respectively
    '''
    return phi_a + (1 - phi_a) / (1 + torch.exp(-phi_c * (x - phi_b)))
```

the they have a custom `Optimization Problem` which we call `custom loss` and I have defined it as follows:

```
# Custom loss function
def custom_loss(Y_true, Y_pred, L, R, mu):
    '''
    In the paper, it given as:
    BCE Loss + ((mu/2) * (Frobenius norm of L squared + Frobenius norm of R squared))
    and Frobenius_norm(L) = √(Σ (L_ij)^2) so the authors might have used square just to eliminate the square root value so it becomes: Σ(L_ij)^2
    '''
    bce_loss = torch.nn.BCELoss()(Y_pred, Y_true)
    frobenius_norm_L = torch.sum(L ** 2)
    frobenius_norm_R = torch.sum(R ** 2)
    reg_loss = (mu / 2) * (frobenius_norm_L + frobenius_norm_R)
    return bce_loss + reg_loss
```

There are some conditions given in the image below as:

1. `0 <= L_uj <= 1` : All the entries in `Student - Latent Topic`matrix `L` will be between [0,1]
2. `0 <= R_qj <= 1` : All the entries  in `Latent Topic - Question` matrix `R` will be between [0,1]
3. Sum of all the elements of `R_qj` in each row must be equal to 1. It means if each questio is represented by `n_topics` then sum of `n_topics` for each question will be exactly equal to 1 (Like Softmax)
4. Paper uses Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) method to solve the matrix factorization problem

then somehow (by hook or crook with lots of help), I reached to a point where I bumped into **some** solution as:

```
# Dummy numbers
n_students = 50
n_questions = 700
n_concepts = 15

# Hyperparameters 
n_epochs = 10
learning_rate = 0.01
mu = 0.1  # regularization 

# Given constants for the phi() function
phi_a, phi_b, phi_c = 0.25, 0.5, 10 

# ---------------------------------------------------
# Generate random student responses (1 if correct, 0 otherwise)
Y = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n_students, n_questions))
L = np.random.rand(n_students, n_concepts) # Initialize L and R matrices randomly
R = np.random.rand(n_questions, n_concepts)

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([L, R], lr=learning_rate) # SGD as given

# -------------------------------------------------------------

# Training loop
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    X = torch.matmul(L, torch.transpose(R, 0, 1))
    Y_pred = phi(X) # predicted score
    loss = custom_loss(Y, Y_pred, L, R, mu)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    # Enforce 3 conditions
    R.data = R.data / R.data.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)  # Normalize rows of R to sum up to 1
    L.data = torch.clamp(L.data, min=0, max=1) # 0 ≤ L[u, j] ≤ 1 
    R.data = torch.clamp(R.data, min=0, max=1) # 0 ≤ R[q, j] ≤ 1


# Calculate the optimized understanding matrix X_opt (n_students x n_questions)
X_opt = torch.matmul(L, torch.transpose(R, 0, 1))

# --- Evaluate  --------------------------------

# Calculate the probability score for a student u and question q using the modified sigmoid function
u, q = 0, 4
probability_score = phi(X_opt[u, q]) # Given in the formula
print(f"Probability score for student {u} and question {q}: {probability_score.item()}")
```

**Now the problem is that I don't know whether it is the right solution and is giving the results it should be giving**.

PS: If this can be solved by any other method, please do let me know. I just want to replicate the paper by using Any library.

Answer (score 0):

All you did seems reasonable.

The missing part is the synthetic data generation:
Randomize `L` and `R`, then obtain

```
X = torch.matmul(L, torch.transpose(R, 0, 1))
Y_train = phi(X)
```

Then generate in the same way `Y_validation`.
`Y_train` is used in your training loop, `Y_validation` is used to evaluate the final performance.